# Sistema De Suscripción Con Moneda Virtual

Tags: nodejs, sqlite3

Pongo la situación de lo que estoy tratando de hacer: - Estoy creando un sistema de suscripción donde se cobra a una moneda virtual(de la pagina) y quiero hacer que cada mes se cobre exactamente 1200 monedas, de no tener la cantidad necesaria dar por desactivado la suscripción y borrar el dato en la db.

```
        let existsUser = await db.existsUser(userid)
if(existsUser) {
    let data = await db.getUser(userid)
    let monedas = data.monedas
    let comp = monedas > 1200
    if(!comp) {
        req.flash('mensajeRegistro', 'No tienes el dinero suficiente')
        res.redirect('/select')
    } else {
        await db.addGuild(serverid)
        req.flash('mensajeRegistro', 'Compra Con exito')
        res.redirect(`/manager/${serverid}`)
        
    }
} else {
    req.flash('mensajeRegistro', 'No tienes el dinero suficiente')
    res.redirect('/select')
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Por favor, evita repetir las preguntas... con usar el boton [edit] y agregar lo que se te pide alcanza... procura mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Comment: Cual seria el problema con este codigo?

Comment: no se como hacer para hacer una función que se repita cada mes donde compruebe si se puede continuar con la suscripción, de lo contrario se cancele la suscripción
en pocas palabras como puedo ejecutar una función cada cierto tiempo